# Cordova Android: Can I get any information on underlying Java/HTTP exceptions

Tags: java, android, angular, cordova

I have an Ionic/Cordova Android application that is deployed on various different client internal networks, where the application connects to a http service running on that internal network, using the Angular HTTP client.

Recently one of our clients finally upgraded from Android 5 to Android 12, and the application would no longer connect to the server, where they were using a self-signed HTTP certificate.

Following [information here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config), we see the following:

```
The default configuration for apps targeting Android 6.0 (API level 23) and lower is as follows:

<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" />
        <certificates src="user" />
    </trust-anchors>
</base-config>
```

So I added this to the manifest file, ie in config.xml I added

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
  </edit-config>
```

And this solved the problem on that particular network.

I also tested this on my office using both http and https and all worked fine.

Now I have another client where they are *not* using certificates, just unsecured http (I also have `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`), and their connection no longer works. The Angular http client just returns `status code 0`. Whenever there are any weird issues with network, this is all I ever get, with absolutely no information as to what is wrong.

My question is, underneath, would there be any extra native (Java) exception information logged to any sort of application/system, log, where I could see what is going wrong here, as I have no idea and connect reproduce the problem (I cannot get to the server in question, is is behind a firewall in another country), so any diagnostics need to be run on a client's mobile device, so I cannot install any SDK, root the phone etc, turn on dev mode etc. I just want to see if there are any errors logged (as you could, for example on a Windows desktop event viewer).

Is there any way to get any extra information on what may be going with the HTTP call here?

Comment: If you are using a self-signed certificate why don't you use network security configuration to trust this certificate instead of just trust user and system store? https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#ConfigCustom

Comment: Wouldn't the network security configuration involve *hardwiring* in a the CA to just to one service instance, in on a particular intranet? I.e. need this to be something generic? Also not sure why anything here would cause a deployment not even using TLS to fail (and yet it does)?

Comment: Correct I wasn't aware that all of your clients get the same version. I would really recommend to build different flavors - not for every customer but at least for the non-https people. To my experience customers concerned about security prefer if apps disable insecure modes (wait we are talking about Cordova then security is already gone but that entry can make it much worse). Regarding logging I am not sure how much logging you can get especially on Java level because the used WebView implementation is implemented natively and thus as not much to to with the Java level.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping that perhaps the Webview (which is of course native code) would log out any Java exceptions - but incredibly Android logs seem impossible to get to in production, with out having developer mode, rooted phone, dev environment etc? I am hoping there is a way to do this (i.e. get to logs). There may be nothing there, but can at least check. Allowing non https at all is an argument for another day, at the moment my requirement it to allow it (perhaps in the future we may mandate TLS even for private  internal networks behind a firewall).

Comment: My problem (this time) was that I didn't actually have the cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" in the added networkSecurityConfig; I had left it in the application level of the xml. Once I moved this to the networkSecurityConfig.xml, it worked again. Running a native test app. the exception thrown told me it was the cleartextTrafficPermitted problem straight away, but this is just not passed up to the ajax call (very frustrating). But the question here remains, is there a way (for the next time) to get an Android logs.

Comment: Monitoring exceptions of remote apps (apps on customer devices) is typically the job of analytics frameworks like Google Analytics. If you want to check the log locally just use `adb logcat`. Usually the exceptions shown there that happens because of changes in new Android versions are very verbose and often contain the description what to do to solve them. Note that some times those logs occur not in the process itself but on system level so filtering for the app pid will prevent you from seeing them.